# Google Play Services maps 6.5 How do I manually trigger the Map Toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

With Google Play Services 6.5, various updates were made to SupportMapFragment and MapFragment, including the automatic addition of the map toolbar, which is a small bar that shows up when you click on a marker, as seen here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html

For my application, I am overriding the maps [OnMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html) with my own, so that I can handle some custom things, including overriding the default behaviour where the camera snaps to the position of the marker.

When I override the maps OnMarkerClickListener, I have found that this in turn overrides the default behaviour where the map toolbar automatically shows when a user clicks a marker. My question is, can I somehow cause this toolbar to show automatically in my custom OnMarkerClickListener, or am I basically going to lose the toolbar feature since I am overriding the marker click?

Comment: What happens if you call through to super first but then return true from your overridden implementation? Feels a bit weird, but would be interested to know the result.

Comment: Sadly since you can only set a listener, you cannot really call the super first, you can only return true if you want the super to perform its actions as well.

Comment: Ah, true, of course. What I meant to say was more like my recent comment on ztan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to stkent and ztan for leading me to the answer. My original question was how to call the toolbar to come up manually, but it really came out of a need to override the default behaviour of the camera animating to center the marker on the map. You can still trigger the toolbar to show up and keep the camera at its current position like so:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            mRootView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
                       mMap.getCameraPosition().target));
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Basically, the camera will take the update from the system, but in the next frame, since we have posted it, it will get our camera update and our camera update will override the system one, therefore the camera will not move at all. Hope this can help anyone else that has this same issue. You could probably do the same trick if you wanted to override the marker showing its info by putting

```
 marker.hideInfoWindow()
```

in the runnable as well, therefore you would be override the two other operations without overriding the showing of the toolbar.

Comment: Nice find, it's a shame there's not a neater way built-in but any solution at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The toolbar will be shown, as long as your `return false` in the `OnMarkerClickListener()`. I also tested it in my sample app, it shows the botom toolbar when I return false, it doesnt show the toolbar when I return true.

According to the [OnMarkClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html) reference, **true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur).**

Comment: This is true, I had found this out too, but the problem is that part of the purpose of my override is to prevent the map from panning the camera over to the marker. Returning true will cause the map to pan over, so if there was a way to manually trigger the showing of the toolbar, that would solve the problem without the marker having to be centered on the screen.

Comment: Does the map animate even if you explicitly call your own animate camera method with the current camera location inside your listener, and then return false? I'm not sure which camera movement would take precedence in that case.

Comment: I tried it out, and even if I am explicitly animating the camera and then return false, the system takes over and animates the marker to be centered. So it seems like the system takes precedence.